# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\operatorname{Ta}(n)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I made this question up for fun, sorry if it's quite silly.

The $n$-th [Taxicab number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number), typically denoted $\operatorname{Ta}(n)$, is defined as the smallest integer that can be expressed as a sum of two positive integer cubes in $n$ distinct ways. The second Taxicab number, which is also the most famous one, is $1729$. It can be represented as $10^3+9^3$ or $12^3+1^3$. The Taxicab numbers grow really rapidly, for example

$$\operatorname{Ta}(6) = 24153319581254312065344$$

This got me thinking about the following series and whether anything can be said about it's convergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\operatorname{Ta}(n)}$$

How would you prove that this converges? Could you use the fact that $\zeta(3)$ converges to prove the convergence?

The normal Taxicab numbers grow so rapidly that the convergence of the series above is quite certain. However, if we change the definition by Taxicab number slightly by introducing the notation $\operatorname{Tas}(n)$ as being numbers which are sums of two cubes in two or **more** ways, the numbers grow much less rapidly with

$$\operatorname{Tas}(6) = 39312$$

What can then be said about the converge of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\operatorname{Tas}(n)}$$

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^3 + m^3} < +\infty\,.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first series, we use the naïve bound $\operatorname{Ta} (n) \ge n^3$.

This bound is valid since, for $\operatorname{Ta} (n)$ to be expressed as the sum of two cubes in $n$ distinct ways, at least $n$ distinct cubes must be involved, and at least one of them is not less than $n^3$.

Hence $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 2} \frac1{\operatorname{Ta} (n)}<\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 2} \frac1{n^3} = \zeta(3)-1$.

For the second series, we note that each $\operatorname{Tas}$ is just a sum of two cubes. We can thus bound it as follows:

\begin{align}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac1{\operatorname{Tas} (n)} &\le \sum_{1\le m<n}\frac1{m^3+n^3} \\&= \frac1{1^3+1^3} + \frac1{1^3+2^3}+\frac1{2^3+2^3}+\frac1{1^3+3^3}+\frac1{2^3+3^3}+\frac1{3^3+3^3}+\cdots
\\&<\frac1{1^3+1^3}+\frac2{2^3+2^3}+\frac3{3^3+3^3}+\frac4{4^3+4^3} + \cdots
\\&=\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac n{2n^3}\\&=\frac12\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac 1{n^2}=\frac12\zeta(2)\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand why $Ta(n)\ge 1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3$

Comment: @KentaS I mixed up the definition from another site. I'll fix that so that the inequality still hold.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One more question: is it not possible that something like $x^3+x^3=y^3+z^3 (x\ne y\ne z)$ can happen? Even if this could happen, I agree the same argument shows that at least $Ta(n)\ge n^3$

Comment: Euler apparently proved this can't happen: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145877/what-is-the-rational-rank-of-the-elliptic-curve-x3-y3-2

Comment: @KentaS I know of Euler's result (but I forgot where) and I do not wish to use it here. Good catch.